# Unable to use AFNetworkReachabilityManager class to get network reachability in my OS X project

Tags: macos, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

System i am working is OSX(10.11.1),Xcode (7.2.1)
 Pod file is placed in the same directory where we have .xcodeproject
    podfile to include AFNetworking is 
    `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :osx, '10.9'
    target  'EntredaUnifyApplet' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
    end`
Runned the following commands
pod setup
pod install

Aftet that i included below code in my VC and also imported
AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m and AFNetworking.h
snippet i used is

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
}];

[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

When i try to run it, i am getting below error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>         "_AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus", referenced from:
>             ___38-[viewController awakeFromNib]_block_invoke in viewController.o
>         "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkReachabilityManager", referenced from:
>             objc-class-ref in viewController.o
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove those errors, you need to add systemconfiguration framework and libAFNetworking.a in Build phases under link Binary with Libraries. Then these errors will be removed.

Comment: I had installed multiple Cocoapods, so I thought I adding libPods-MyAppName.a would include all the cocoapods, but it did not work. Once I deleted libPods-MyAppName.a and added libApNetworking.a and libFlurry-ios-SDK.a the project compiled.. Thanks for posting this solution.